# On The expansion of $e^x$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, limits, nonstandard-analysis

http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/introductiontoanalysisvol1.htm

The chapter $7$ of this mentions a proof of expansion of $e^x$ without using idea of derivative but only using idea of infinitesimals.
Everything that Euler did was beautiful but I am unable to convince me at this point of the proof,

Euler sets

$j/j=1$,

$(j-1)/j =1$,

$(j-2)/j =1$,

$\quad\vdots$

as the value of $j$ is infinite.
But my question is how long is this true? I mean as the value of $n$ goes to infinity in $(j-n)/j$ will it still be converging to $1$?

It’s clear that it approches $0$. So why did Euler said it's $1$ (its not exactly mentioned by Euler but the information in the para explains this thing).

If possible please explain me that part in an elaborated way as an answer. And please explain me step by step as I am a bit confused regarding it.

Comment: In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.

Comment: It sounds more like it is saying that $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\dfrac{i-n}{i}=1$ which is indeed true for all finite values of $n$.  Informally, one might write this as $\dfrac{\infty-n}{\infty}=1$ which is again true for all finite values of $n$... but this is dangerous to write as it implies $\infty$ can be used in arithmetic expressions.  There are contexts where this is done, but real analysis is generally not one.  It is better to avoid using $\infty$ as a number unless the specific situation absolutely requires it, and great care should be used in those cases.

Comment: "*As the value of $n$ goes to infinity... Its clear that it approaches $0$*"  Be careful about mixing up order of limits.  The three limits:  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\dfrac{i-n}{i}$, $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{i-n}{i}$, and $\lim\limits_{(i,n)\to (\infty,\infty)}\dfrac{i-n}{i}$ are not the same and should not be treated as the same.  The first goes to $1$.  The second goes to $-\infty$.  The third does not converge as it depends on the path taken.

Comment: That link is interesting.  The non-rigorous manipulations Euler did to arrive at his conclusions make him seem like a mad genius.

Comment: A lot of mathematicians like Euler, Gauss, Jacobi and most famously Ramanujan were great experts in formal manipulation of infinite series (and other similar infinite stuff) and they knew when such manipulation would lead to a correct result and when it would fail. The development of rigor sort of put all these ideas out there for mere mortals like us.

Comment: JMoravitz , I upvoted your comment and request a complete answer.

Comment: JMoravitz, and also I don't understand how

Comment: lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\dfrac{i-n}{i

Comment: Approach 1. Sorry for that interruption in the comment.

Comment: @JMoravitz I would assume that the second limit is $0$ (provided that $i\in\mathbb Z_+$). Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you see that the limit of the constant sequence where all terms in the sequence are $1$ will be identically equal to $1$?  If we were to step into the realm of the extended reals for a moment and define a function $f~:~(\Bbb R\cup \{-\infty,\infty\})\to (\Bbb R\cup \{-\infty,\infty\})$ given by $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in \Bbb R\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ do you see why $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$?  Note that it doesn't matter what $f(\infty)$ actually is... all that matters is how $f$ acts as $x$ **approaches** (*but doesn't equal*) infinity.

Comment: This is just like how $g~:~\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ given by $g(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\neq 5\\0&\text{if }x=5\end{cases}$ has $\lim\limits_{x\to 5}g(x)=1$ despite the fact that $g(5)=0$.  Now... $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} \dfrac{i-n}{i}\right) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1\right) = 1$ since for every finite value of $n$ you have the inner limit evaluates identically to $1$.  By the time you have evaluated the inner limit and are ready to consider the outer limit, you are dealing with a constant sequence.  We never actually reach a point where $i=n=\infty$.